# How to abort getChar safely?

Tags: haskell, io

I would like to optionally abort a `getChar` action.
I need the following function:

```
getChar' :: (Char -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())
```

In case of `abort <- getChar' callback` , a character is read from standard input, unless `abort` is called before a character is available.
If a character is read, `callback` is called with it.

I have the following prototype implementation:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent

getChar' :: (Char -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())
getChar' callback = do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    tid <- forkIO $ do
        c <- getChar
        b <- tryPutMVar v ()
        when b $ callback c
    return $ do
        b <- tryPutMVar v ()
        when b $ killThread tid
```

The problem is that `killThread` may abort the thread after reading the char but before putting `()` into the MVar.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, is it possible at all with the base package?
If not, have you seen a similar function implemented in other packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to perform your own buffering. Here's a simple prototype. It assumes that you call `launchIOThread` exactly once in your program. It doesn't handle EOF or other IO exceptions, but that should be easy.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

type Buffer = TVar (Maybe Char)

launchIOThread :: IO Buffer
launchIOThread = do
  buf <- atomically $ newTVar Nothing
  _ <- forkIO $ ioThread buf
  return buf

ioThread :: Buffer -> IO ()
ioThread buf = loop where
  loop =
    join $ atomically $ do
      contents <- readTVar buf
      if isJust contents -- no-one has taken the character yet
        then retry -- relax
        else return $ do
          c <- getChar
          atomically $ writeTVar buf (Just c)
          loop

getChar' :: Buffer -> (Char -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())
getChar' buf callback = do
  abortFlag <- atomically $ newTVar False

  _ <- forkIO $ doGetChar abortFlag

  return $ atomically $ writeTVar abortFlag True

  where
    doGetChar abortFlag = join $ atomically $ do
      mbC <- readTVar buf
      abort <- readTVar abortFlag
      case mbC of
        Just c ->
          do writeTVar buf Nothing; return $ callback c
        Nothing | abort -> return $ return ()
        _ -> retry
```

Comment: Thanks! Is STM and a global buffer inevitable here? What do you think, could `getChar` be defined in `IO` too without compromising its semantics? Edit: I guess yes because `IO` may have global state.

Comment: I am wondering why `getChar' :: (Char -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())` is not in `Prelude` or `System.IO`, it has simple semantics and it seems impossible to define with existing constructs (I mean without your `Buffer` parameter).

Comment: 1. Yes, there are hacks to create global variables in Haskell.

Comment: 2. Prelude is a module like any other. Placing something it Prelude does not make it magical. Perhaps you mean why this functionality is not provided by GHC's own IO system. I guess, nobody just bothered to do it...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use exception-handling constructs such that regardless of exceptions, the MVar is always left in a safe state. In particular, you probably want `withMVar`.

Comment: The problem is there even if we suppose that `getChar` raises no exceptions, so `withMVar` does not help.